# Make Rails Concern more adaptable by passing an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I try to use a Concern to validate ActiveStorage::Attached, like:

```ruby
module AttachmentValidator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validates :validate_attachment
  end

  def validate_attachment
     errors.add(attachment_name, "Unsupported type") if attachment_name.byte_size > 10.megabytes
  end
```

where `attachment_name` is the attachment association name which differs from model to model, like `avatar`, `file`,... and the `validate_attachment` method is more complex than in this example.

So I would like to pass the actual name to the concern while including it to the model, something like this:

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include AttachmentValidator :avatar
```

So far I have tried to call a class method to define the variable, but there will be a `ThreadSafety/InstanceVariableInClassMethod` warning.

Is there a to modify the concern, so it know the right denotation for each attachment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAGNI. You can make validators by subclassing `ActiveModel::Validator` or `ActiveModel::EachValidator`:

```
# app/validators/attachment_size_validator.rb 
class AttachmentSizeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.byte_size > 10.megabytes    
      record.errors.add(attribute, "Unsupported type")  
    end
  end
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :avatar, attachment_size: true
end
```

Creating simple validation methods is good for simple use cases. But not if your want to be able to reuse the validation.

> So I would like to pass the actual name to the concern while including it to the model

You can't actually pass additional arguments when including modules. It's just not part of the underlying Module#included hook provided by Ruby.

If you do want to make the functionality provided by a module configurable you can do it by adding a class method to the module:

```
# this is just a silly example
module Frobnobizer
  include ActiveSupport::Concern
   
  class_methods do
    def frobnobize(attribute)
      validates attribute, unique: true,
                           presence: true
    end
  end 
end
  
class User
  include Frobnobizer
  frobnobize(:name)
end
```

You can also use class methods on the including class to change what happens when a module is included.

```
class User
  # ...
  def self.attachment_attribute_name
    :foo_bar_baz
  end
end


module AttachmentValidator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do 
    attribute = self.try(:attachment_attribute_name, :some_default_value)
    validates attribute, ... 
  end
```

The former approach is generally prefereable though as it allows more flexibity.